# jquery to goto a url on form submit with field values added to the url string

Tags: jquery, string, url, parameters

I'm fairly new to jquery and I think this is simple but I'm struggling and google doesn't seem to be helping....

What I have is a basic form...

```
<form>
First Name: < input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" />
Surname: < input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Now when submit is clicked I want to goto a url but then add the froms values to the url string (but not using the form method=get) basicly I want this to happen

on click of submit goto `http://myurl.com/index.html?params=firstNamevalue*surnamevalue`

I've been hacking about with the jquery but where I'm upto is something like this...

```
< script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript">< /script>
< script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1.3.1");
</script>

< script type="text/javascript">

var = firstName $("#firstName").val();
var = surname $("#surname").val();


$('#submit').click(function(){
  window.location = ???;
}); 
< /script>
```

hopefully I've been farily clear - I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Andy

Comment: Why exactly can't you use `<form method="get">` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you both for your help on this...

I'm not sure if I was doing something wrong with your methods or if I hadn't described what I needed to do well enough...

The solution in the end for me was this...

first file contains a a form with `method="get"`

```
< form method="get" action="getParams.html">
First Name: < input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" />
Surname: < input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" />
< input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>
< /form>
```

this directs to get params and as the method=get the url ends with `getParams.html?firstname=""&surname=""`

Then in the `getParams.html` page this is simply used for the formatting (as i need it to be) from the url and redirect...

I used attached jquery followed by this plugin `http : // projects.allmarkedup.com/jquery_url_parser/`

with the js:

```
var firstName = jQuery.url.param("firstName");
var surname = jQuery.url.param("surname");
location.href = 'http://myOnlineMag/issue01.html?params=' + firstName + '*' + surname;
```

pulls the values I want form the url as vars then attaches them to the end of my url. (I needed these in this specific format - can't share a link until the projects live but I can post next week if you would like.)

Answer (score 11):

[jQuery serialize](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize) might help in a simple case like the one you describe:

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
  location.href = 'index.html'+$(this).serialize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have it right, almost.

```
var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
var surname = $("#surname").val();

location.href = "index.html?firstName=" + firstName + "&surname=" + surname
```

Of course, you could make a function that accepts a list of key/value pairs in an object and make this generic, but you get the idea.

```
$('#submit').click( function() { 
location.href = "";
return false;
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys been trying this afternoon and still can't quiet get it right... this is what I have 

var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
var surname = $("#surname").val();
$('#submit').click(location.href = "http://public.edition-on.net/352online/issue01.html?params=" + firstName + "*" + surname);

but it forwards on page load rather than on click??

I'm gonna keep trying but obvo any futher pointers would be appreciated...

Andy