# How to get the full target url of a form with get methood

Tags: javascript

I have a form that has a lot of hidden input elements being added to it by javascript. I don't have access to the site the form is pointing to and there are a lot of server side URL redirects so I can't debug my javascript.

If I set something like this:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Some way to see the full URL where this form would point to
});
```

It would help me out a lot in matching my URL to one provided by the client.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery to goto a url on form submit with field values added to the url string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610214/jquery-to-goto-a-url-on-form-submit-with-field-values-added-to-the-url-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(this.action);
```

The action attribute should be available on the form element.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/zq4tku7r/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this didn't come to me earlier

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $('#myform').attr('action')
    $('#myForm select, #myForm input').each(function(index, element){
        var $element = $(element);
        url += $element.attr('name') + '=' + $element.val();
        url += (('#myForm select, #myForm input').length != index ? '&' : '');
    })
    console.log(url);
});
```